# Storing xbee source addr into database in Python

Tags: python, mysql, database, xbee

I have raspberry pi connected with xbees and a motion sensor, receiving data from the motion sensor connected to one of the xbee. It would then send the data to my raspberry pi. Is there any way I could manipulate or split the output such as the status being only True/False and the address =\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xbbJ as I wanted to store the address into database if status=="True".

So if I do

```
if status[0]['dio-0'] == True :
            print "Yes"
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("INSERT ignore into sensor(sensor_id, status) VALUES(%s,True)",(add[0]))
            con.commit()
```

But the address stored into the database is weird characters instead of \x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xbbJ. or should I do any other ways?

This is the codes.

```
from xbee import XBee
import serial


PORT = '/dev/ttyUSBXBEE'
BAUD_RATE = 9600

# Open serial port
ser = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD_RATE)

# Create API object
xbee = XBee(ser)

def decodeReceivedFrame(response):
        add = str(response['source_addr_long'])
        status = response['samples']
        return [add, status]

# Continuously read and print packets
while True:
    try:
        response = xbee.wait_read_frame()
        decodedData = decodeReceivedFrame(response)
        status = decodeReceivedFrame(response)[1]
        print status
        print decodedData
        add= decodedData[0]

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

ser.close()
```

And this is the output.

```
[{'dio-0': True}]
['\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xbbJ}', [{'dio-0': True}]]
[{'dio-0': False}]
['\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xbbJ}', [{'dio-0': False}]]
```

In the database

```
+------------+--------+
| sensor_id  | status |
+------------+--------+
|  ¢ @»J}    |  1     |
+------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `sensor_id` is an array of bytes, and it sounds like you want to store it in a human-readable format.

One way is to convert it to a formatted string before storing it in the database.

```
sensor_id = ':'.join("%02X" % ord(b) for b in add)
```

That statement loops through the bytes in the address (`for b in add`), formats each as a two-character hex string (`"%02X" % ord(b)`), and then joins each of those strings together with a colon in between (`':'.join()`).

Comment: Thank you! but is it better to use repr(add) or ':'.join("%02X" % ord(b) for b in add) ?

Comment: This method will provide a more consistent format -- one that will be familiar to more people.  With `repr()`, any printable hex values will appear as an ASCII letter instead of an escaped hex value.  I guess it depends on what you plan to do with the field.  Is the primary user of the database a person, or another computer program?  You could just store it as a 64-bit unsigned integer if people aren't going to read it.

Comment: It's gonna be displayed for people to see too. so I guess this method does it? If I use SQL statements where a.sensor_id=b.sensor_id, dos it affect them?

Comment: Comparisons will work fine.  It's a consistent, unique way to display a given IEEE address.  As long as all insertions are consistently done using that method, you'll be fine.

Comment: I see. Thanks so much